# MSBuild AfterBuild messages not showing real-time

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, csproj

I have something like the following in the .csproj file for an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <CallTarget Targets="InstallBuildDependencies" />
  <CallTarget Targets="BuildAssets" />
</Target>
<Target Name="InstallBuildDependencies">
  <Message Text="Installing build dependencies:" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
</Target>
  <Target Name="BuildAssets">
  <Message Text="Building assets:" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="grunt build" />
</Target>
```

and something like this in a .pubmxl for the same project:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Other properties here -->
    <InstallBuildDependenciesCmd>npm install</InstallBuildDependenciesCmd>
    <BuildDistAssetsCmd>grunt dist</BuildDistAssetsCmd>
    <PipelineDependsOn>
      InstallBuildDependencies;
      BuildDistAssets;
    </PipelineDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="InstallBuildDependencies">
    <Message Text="Installing build dependencies:" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="$(InstallBuildDependenciesCmd)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildDistAssets" AfterTargets="InstallBuildDependencies">
    <Message Text="Building distribution assets:" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="$(BuildDistAssetsCmd)" />
  </Target>
```

The issue is that, in the first snippet, none of the messages or output from the commands displays in the Ouput console in Visual Studio until everything in the build has finished. This is not ideal since it would be better to see the messages and command output in "real-time".

In the second snippet, both the messages and command output DO show in "real-time" in the Output console.

Is it possible to get the messages from the first first snippet to display in real-time like the messages in the second snippet do? Why am I experiencing this inconsistency?

Comment: no experience with mvc, but *AfterBuild* likely happens after everything (?) else is build, so doesn't it make sense you only see the messages at the end of the build only? Whereas with the second snippet you seem to make your targets dependencies of something in the build, so they would be called earlier then with the AfterBuild snippets and so they're shown earlier in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Try use `DependsOnTargets` instead of `CallTarget`:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="InstallBuildDependencies,BuildAssets">
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Super late answer, but recently stumbled with this same issue.
It seems that this is not possible, according to the [Exec Task documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task) in the *Remarks* section:

> However, the Exec task, unlike a more specific task, cannot gather output from the tool or command that it runs.

Hope this saves some time for anyone else.