# Visual Studio MSBuild exec task - output window buffer flush

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

My build process involves an `Exec` task that runs a console program.

```
<Target Name="TestTask" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command='program.exe" />
</Target>
```

The program's output is shown in the "output" window, but only after the task has finished (all at once). How can I see the output gradually? It's a long-running task that reports a lot of thing as it goes...

UPD: found a relevant question with a workaround: [MSBuild AfterBuild messages not showing real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125377/msbuild-afterbuild-messages-not-showing-real-time)

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio MSBuild exec task - output window buffer flush

I`d like provide your a workaround for this issue, but I am not sure if it exactly meets your requirements.

To accomplish this, you could try putting the execute command in a batch file and invoking the batch file instead. Not very elegant but might do the trick. The batch file like:

```
start /d "<PathForTheProgram.exe>" program.exe
```

Or you can use Windows power-shell to start the `program.exe` directly:

```
  <Target Name="TestTask" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" >
    <Exec Command="powershell start-process  &quot;<PathForEXE>\program.exe &quot;" />
  </Target>
```

The different is that the program's output is shown in the command prompt window not inside in the Visual Studio output window.

Hope this helps.